# Error in using the reshape function in matlab

Tags: matlab

This is a section of code from my program

```
%read in the message image and reshape it into a vector
file_name='innocence.bmp';
message=double(imread(file_name));
Mm=size(message,1);   %height 
Nm=size(message,2);   %Width 
message_vector=round(reshape(message,Mm*Nm,1)./2);
```

I am getting this error

```
??? Error using ==> reshape
TO RESHAPE the number of elements must not change.
Error in ==>dwt at 31  message_vector=round(reshape(message,Mm*Nm,1)./2);
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: What is the value of `Mm` and `Nm`? (Remove the semicolons to check)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you just want to reshape your [Mm x Nm] matrix to a [1 x Mm*Nm] vector you can use:

```
message_vector=round(message(:)/2);
```

Comment: Thanks,this worked but i am getting errors in the later part of the code.I am working on digital image watermarking have found the dwt matlab code for the same but it is not giving the proper results.Please help me out to debug it.Here is the code[Google](http://read.pudn.com/downloads90/sourcecode/crypt/342983/dwtwatermark/dwt_embed.m__.htm)